# In OOP, are all class methods valid?

Tags: object-oriented, abstraction

Some classes have methods that don't match up with procedural data abstraction. Here is an example of a problem hierarchy, the `Render()` method doesn't seem to be part of an procedural data abstraction (required for ADT) at all.

My question is should the `Render()` function be inside the class anyway and why?

```cpp
#include <SomeGfxLib.h>

class Shape {
public:
    virtual void Render() = 0;
private:
    Color tint;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    virtual void Render() {
        SomeGfxLib::DrawCircle(); // call complex drawing procedures
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you define "valid?"

Comment: I feel your question is a bit unclear; it would help if you defined key terms. For example, the term "procedural data abstraction (PDA)" comes from William Cook as a more precise name for OOP. Cook makes a distinction between ADTs and objects of OOP, and calls the abstraction mechanism behind objects the *procedural abstraction* (in line with the code you've presented), but asserts that ADTs are based on *data abstraction* (not the case here, in that specific sense). Now, you can find these and similar terms used in somewhat different ways, so expanding on the question would be really helpful.

Comment: References: [Cook 1990](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/wcook/papers/OOPvsADT/CookOOPvsADT90.pdf) & [Cook 2009](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf)

Comment: BTW, I'm not saying that you have to use those terms in the same way these papers do, just that we who are reading your question might not be thinking of the same concepts as you are, so I'm really just asking you to expand on what you mean when you say "doesn't seem to be part of an procedural data abstraction (required for ADT)". Like, in what way? What expectations aren't met in this example, so that you reach that conclusion? Be more explicit about the specific thing that's bugging you.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović You're right! i completely forgot about that paper! That explains my error, thank you very much!

Comment: @FilipMilovanović very interesting papers which seem to explain very well OP’s confusion. Let me know if you’d make an answer with a brief summary and the reference, I’ll upvote. This contribution really deserves not to be lost in some comments :-)

Comment: @Christophe I'll do it if I find time, but I'm not yet entirely sure how I'd go about it, I see two potential problems: (1) since the OP didn't provide further clarification, I'm not sure what their confusion was specifically, so the content of the answer would likely end up being in more generalized terms then I'd like, and (2) I'm not sure how well I can summarize the papers while keeping the length of the answer reasonable - I need to find some way of getting the key points across without requiring too much exposition.

Answer (score 5):

If your design is to have such a method, the method is “valid”.  Now if it is a good idea depends on how you intend to solve the problem with your design.

You can render a simple 2D wire-frame scene by rendering each shape of a collection one after the other. But the problem here is the separation of concerns: now all your shapes are coupled to your graphic library.  If you change library, and perhaps even platform, you’ll have a huge work.

A more evolutive way could be to use the [bridge pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern): your shape abstraction stays uncorrupted by your graphic environment. It relies on an implementation layer that can evolve independently to the shapes. Each method of the abstraction invokes one or several low level methods of the implementor.

*Note that I wrote “more evolutive”. Not “better”. It’s a question of balance: I want evolutivity, it’ll cost me some complexity. There is no free lunch.*

Now, back to your question: maybe there’s a deeper conceptual problem. For example you may want the renderer to decide which shape to draw and which part is hidden.  In this case, the current rendering design would be insufficient.  In this case you may need a `Renderer` object that interacts with the shapes. Maybe it’s even a combination of both, with a shape abstraction having a shape implementor that acts as a proxy in a colection owned by the `Renderer`?

There a plenty of ways this can be modeled. We can’t tell what’s best. If you tell more, we can help you find what’s most suitable.

Comment: Thanks for your input, i think the problem is i was considering the class not as a type but as an object

Answer (score 5):

There are four reasons to hang a function on an object:

1. Provide the function access to the private state of that object
2. Group conceptually similar functions together
3. Polymorphism, that is, to change the implementation of this function as other functions on that object change their implementation.
4. Because you’re an Object Oriented zealot who thinks every function should be hanging from an object

If you can’t point at one of the first three then the fourth is pointing at you.

Comment: There are other good reasons.  For example, if most or all of the data / information used by the function reside in the object.  Or, if adding the function simplifies the API or allows for greater information hiding.

Comment: @user949300 that’s reason 1. It allows such data to be kept private.

Comment: Not as you worded it.  The function need not _provide_ access to anybody outside.  Ideally, it _hides_ access.

Comment: @user949300 better now?

Comment: You flipped my frown to a smile.

Comment: @user949300 thanks for the feed back. I simply couldn’t see the other way to read it.

Comment: There is also a point 4b: The language-designer was/is a zealot for OO purity and foisted it on all users.

Comment: And the what is the answer to the question asked: “should the Render() function be inside the class and why” ?

Comment: @Christophe the way it's currently implemented it doesn't use any object state so 1 is out. There is no other function to conceptually group it with so 2 is out. It is virtual so it might have a polymorphic use but I only see one implementation so right now it's BDUF. Some improvement might fix that but right now all I can see is 4. But I don't really care because I'm aiming for an answer that is useful to more people than just the OP.

Comment: @candied_orange Having an abstract base class Shape and a single implementation Circle is hardly BDUF. In that line of thinking any way of looking beyond your nose's length is BDUF.

Comment: @MartinMaat Calling it BDUF is gentle. Some wont let you use `virtual` without a good justification. I'm not calling for a micro optimization. I'm just saying it's BDUF until you show me at least `TestCircle`. You're writing code that *might* be useful. YAGNI is sometimes wrong. But it's the right conversation to have here. Otherwise everything gets an abstract base class. Sometimes the wrong abstract base class.